# Images Side by Side in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot believe I am asking this question, but how can I get these two images to go side by side on the same level? I set both of the image containers to `display: inline-block;` and it is not placing them side by side, yet one above the other.

Live example:

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
    "particles": {
        "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "value_area": 800
            }
        },
        "color": {
            "value": "#b3ab7d"
        },
        "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
                "width": 0,
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
                "nb_sides": 5
            },
            "image": {
                "src": "img/github.svg",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 100
            }
        },
        "opacity": {
            "value": 1,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 1,
                "opacity_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "size": {
            "value": 3,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 40,
                "size_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#104723",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
        },
        "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 5,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "bounce": false,
            "attract": {
                "enable": false,
                "rotateX": 600,
                "rotateY": 1200
            }
        }
    },
    "interactivity": {
        "detect_on": "window",
        "events": {
            "onhover": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
        },
        "modes": {
            "grab": {
                "distance": 400,
                "line_linked": {
                    "opacity": 1
                }
            },
            "bubble": {
                "distance": 400,
                "size": 40,
                "duration": 2,
                "opacity": 8,
                "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4
            },
            "push": {
                "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
                "particles_nb": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "retina_detect": true
});
```

```css
.img_container {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 45%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.landinghead {
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#img1 {
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
#img2 {
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
        object-fit: cover;
}
.projectInfo{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 130%;
}
 #particles-js{
     position:absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
       z-index: -1;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     background-image: url("");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Projects Landing Page</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<body>
    <h3 class="landinghead">Projects Landing Page</h3>
    <span class ="projectInfo">Here you will find a collection of Active/Ongoing Projects</span>

    <div class="center">
        <div class="img_container">
            <a href="www.google.com">
                <img src="https://api.army.mil/e2/c/images/2021/01/26/4c5cde5d/max1200.jpg" id="img1"/>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="img_container">
            <a href="www.google.com">
              <img src="https://api.army.mil/e2/c/images/2021/01/20/153dc153/max1200.jpg" id="img2"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.img_container` has a width of 100%, so it's stretching to the edge of the page, blocking the next element from moving up

Comment: @RobinClower smh...  I do that and the images are technically "in-line" but not even, can I get them to fill the div so they both take up the same amount of space?

Comment: You can use `img : { object-fit: cover; }` in CSS to make the image cover the area of the div. It might cut off edges to make the image fit.

Comment: @Kokodoko per my most recent edit, it doesn't do anything to the images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code:

Add one flex container, float to left and edit the width and height value:

```
//Style.css
.container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.img_container {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#img1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#img2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

//Html
<div class="center container">
```

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
    "particles": {
        "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "value_area": 800
            }
        },
        "color": {
            "value": "#b3ab7d"
        },
        "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
                "width": 0,
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
                "nb_sides": 5
            },
            "image": {
                "src": "img/github.svg",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 100
            }
        },
        "opacity": {
            "value": 1,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 1,
                "opacity_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "size": {
            "value": 3,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 40,
                "size_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#104723",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
        },
        "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 5,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "bounce": false,
            "attract": {
                "enable": false,
                "rotateX": 600,
                "rotateY": 1200
            }
        }
    },
    "interactivity": {
        "detect_on": "window",
        "events": {
            "onhover": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
        },
        "modes": {
            "grab": {
                "distance": 400,
                "line_linked": {
                    "opacity": 1
                }
            },
            "bubble": {
                "distance": 400,
                "size": 40,
                "duration": 2,
                "opacity": 8,
                "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4
            },
            "push": {
                "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
                "particles_nb": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "retina_detect": true
});
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.img_container {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
   float: left;
}
.landinghead {
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#img1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#img2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.projectInfo{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 130%;
}
 #particles-js{
     position:absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
       z-index: -1;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     background-image: url("");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Projects Landing Page</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<body>
    <h3 class="landinghead">Projects Landing Page</h3>
    <span class ="projectInfo">Here you will find a collection of Active/Ongoing Projects</span>

    <div class="center container">
        <div class="img_container">
            <a href="www.google.com">
                <img src="https://api.army.mil/e2/c/images/2021/01/26/4c5cde5d/max1200.jpg" id="img1"/>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="img_container">
            <a href="www.google.com">
              <img src="https://api.army.mil/e2/c/images/2021/01/20/153dc153/max1200.jpg" id="img2"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your image container, you can add the following.

```
float:left;
```

Full Code:

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
    "particles": {
        "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "value_area": 800
            }
        },
        "color": {
            "value": "#b3ab7d"
        },
        "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
                "width": 0,
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
                "nb_sides": 5
            },
            "image": {
                "src": "img/github.svg",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 100
            }
        },
        "opacity": {
            "value": 1,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 1,
                "opacity_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "size": {
            "value": 3,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 40,
                "size_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#104723",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
        },
        "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 5,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "bounce": false,
            "attract": {
                "enable": false,
                "rotateX": 600,
                "rotateY": 1200
            }
        }
    },
    "interactivity": {
        "detect_on": "window",
        "events": {
            "onhover": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
        },
        "modes": {
            "grab": {
                "distance": 400,
                "line_linked": {
                    "opacity": 1
                }
            },
            "bubble": {
                "distance": 400,
                "size": 40,
                "duration": 2,
                "opacity": 8,
                "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4
            },
            "push": {
                "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
                "particles_nb": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "retina_detect": true
});
```

```css
.img_container {
    border: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 45%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.landinghead {
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#img1 {
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
#img2 {
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
        object-fit: cover;
}
.projectInfo{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 130%;
}
 #particles-js{
     position:absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
       z-index: -1;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     background-image: url("");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Projects Landing Page</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<body>
    <h3 class="landinghead">Projects Landing Page</h3>
    <span class ="projectInfo">Here you will find a collection of Active/Ongoing Projects</span>

    <div class="center">
        <div class="img_container">
            <a href="www.google.com">
                <img src="https://api.army.mil/e2/c/images/2021/01/26/4c5cde5d/max1200.jpg" id="img1"/>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="img_container">
            <a href="www.google.com">
              <img src="https://api.army.mil/e2/c/images/2021/01/20/153dc153/max1200.jpg" id="img2"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

More information on it [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

Working for me when I add that.

Comment: Nowadays we have tools like [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to make layouts. Although `float` has been way to do it for years, it always was a *hacky way* of getting elements to show up next to each other. I'd suggest that you look into these *newer* methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex to class "center"

```css
.center{
  display:flex
}
```

have look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)